# The expression "independent" in the context of Analytical Mechanics

Tags: linear-algebra, classical-mechanics

In Analytical Mechanics, as physicist, we often use the expression *$q_1, q_2$ are independent coordinates*; however, this is a different concept than what we, as mathematicians, call *linearly-independent* vectors in a vector space.

The reason for that, first of all, since $q_i$'s are scalars, they just span a one-dimensional vector space over the real numbers, and secondly, what *independent* means in this concept is that none of the $q_i$'s is a function of other $q_i$'s, i.e for example, knowing the values of $q_1,q_2,...,q_N$ does not allow one to determine the value of $q_{N+1}$.

I was wondering is there any mathematical theory & field where this kind of relation between variables and relation between them are studies, similar to linear algebra, where we work with vectors, analyse the relation between them, and what we can do with them.

Answer (score 1):

In Analytical Mechanics, you are dealing with the configuration space, which mathematically is a Riemannian manifold, and the $q_i$ are the coordinates in your manifold (they are called generalized coordinates in the Lagrangian context) and the kinetic energy defines the natural metric. On the tangent bundle to that manifold you have defined a function $L(q,q')$ (the Lagrangian) and you minimize the action,which is a functional defined on, for example, all paths on your manifold connecting two points. The mathematical theory behind all this is differential geometry and variational calculus on Riemannian manifolds. In the more symmetric Hamiltonian approach, you are dealing with the phase space (a manifold again) with a canonical symplectic structure on it. Thus, symplectic differential geometry is the mathematical framework in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but throwing a bunch of math terms does not produce an answer. Note, I'm also  a mathematics student, so you don't have to be vague.

Comment: I do not quite get what you mean. The $q_i$ are coordinates in a manifold (this has a precise meaning). They are not coordinates of vectors in a vector space. They are considered independent because you need all of them to fix your point in the configuration space. You need as many coordinates as degrees of freedom your system has. Say, if your system is a double pendulum, you need two angles to determine its configuration. Given the periodicity, your manifold is a torus in that case, with two coordinates, one along the parallels and one along the meridians of the torus.

Comment: I suggest you read V.I. Arnold's book "Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics" The whole mathematical apparatus is very well explained there, including both the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formalism.

Comment: I've plans on reading Arnold's book, not have enough time currently; is there any chance that you can briefly mentioned that "precise meaning" ?

Comment: Sure. A differentiable manifold is a set (technically, a topological space) which is locally diffeomorfic to an open disk in $\mathbb{R}^n$. That means  that any point has a neighborhood where  coordinates can be defined in some bijective way, so your space looks like $\mathbb{R}^n$ locally. Those bijective maps are called charts. You require that on regions where two different charts are defined, the transition between them be differentiable. Examples: parametric curves and surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$. The parameter(s) can be used to "coordinatize" the manifold in that case.